# Receiving shared content using windows phone 8.0

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am working on windows phone application 8.0 not 8.1 
I want to receive shared file into my application 
For E.g :

[image]

I found some code that will allow register file type to be shared with application but no luck ..

> I just want to know is that possible to receive shared file with windows phone 8.0 ?

If not then

> Is there any Other Possible Solution ??

```
 <Extensions>
      <Extension Category="windows.shareTarget">
        <ShareTarget>
          <SupportedFileTypes>
            <FileType>.txt</FileType>
        </ShareTarget>
      </Extension>
    </Extensions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with 8.0, only with 8.1.